# Bug in vote count?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I tried looking at vote counts for an answer (with a net negative vote count) and for a question with positive votes. Both from the same thread.

For the answer I see this:

> [image]

And for the question it works fine:

> [image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Seeing that this causes confusion, I've pushed a fix that will say "This post has been deleted", instead of the current, nebulous error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer has probably been deleted since you loaded the Q&A pair. As you don't have the ["moderator-tools" privilege](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), that allows you to see deleted posts, fetching the vote count failed.

This is standard and known behavior, so [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).